# python equivalent to javascript's responseType = "arraybuffer";

Tags: python, python-requests, http-headers

I'm using pythons requests library to make a get request that returns a arraybuffer.

when I use `requests.get(url)`, I end up getting back the text response which is very different from the arraybuffer response I am looking for.

I am able to get the arraybuffer response in node / js with this

```
req.onload = function(event) {
    var res = req.response;
    console.log(res)
}
req.open("GET", url, true);
req.responseType = "arraybuffer";
res = req.send()
```

However, if `req.responseType = "arraybuffer"` is excluded I get the incorrect text response, similar to in python

what is this equivalent to `req.responseType = "arraybuffer"` in python requests (or another python http library)?

Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests
r = requests.get(url)
retArray = [int(i) for i in r.content]

# It seems that variable retArray is much like the arraybuffer in the browser.
# you can try it out.
```